# How to refer to server class located in a different folder/package

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, package

I'm trying to implement a multi client server program. I decided to implement each client program in a different folder/package. Similarly, the server program will be in a different package. So, when I'm creating a socket on the client side and need to refer to the server, how do i go about it? If the server was on a different computer, I'd provide the IP address.

```
Socket clientscoket = new Socket("server.java", 2100);
```

This works when the server program resides in the same directory. What if the server program resides in a different directory?

EDIT:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

class ServerSide {
    static private HashMap<String, Socket> clientList = new HashMap<String, Socket>();

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        ServerSide ss = new ServerSide();
        new Listener(argv[0]);    
    }
}

class Listener implements Runnable {
    ServerSocket listenSocket;
    HashMap<String, Socket> hm = new HashMap<String, Socket>();

    Listener(String prt) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        String output;
        listenSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(prt));
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public Listener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // List<Socket> cList = new ArrayList<Socket>();
    // Create a new Thread. One for listening. Another for comms
    public void run() {
        boolean cont = true;
        while (cont) {
            Socket connectionSocket;
            try {
                connectionSocket = listenSocket.accept();
                new ClientThread(connectionSocket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /*
         * BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new
         * InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
         * System.out.println("Input Stream created"); String cid =
         * inFromClient.readLine(); System.out.println(cid+" connected");
         * PrintWriter outToClient = new
         * PrintWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
         * outToClient.println("Hello "+cid); clientSentence =
         * inFromClient.readLine(); welcomeSocket.close(); cont = false;
         * 
         * System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
         * capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
         * outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
         */
    }

    public HashMap<String, Socket> getMap() {
        return hm;
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    String msg;
    Thread t;
    BufferedReader ipStream;
    boolean flag = true;
    Listener l = new Listener();

    ClientThread(Socket connectionSocket) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("We're here");
        t = new Thread(this);
        ipStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        if (ipStream.ready()) {
            String cid = ipStream.readLine();
            t.setName(cid);
            System.out.println(t.getName() + " connected");
            l.getMap().put(cid, connectionSocket);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (flag) {
                if (ipStream.ready()) {
                    System.out.println("Stream ready");
                    msg = ipStream.readLine();
                    if (msg.equals("close")) {
                        System.out.println(t.getName() + " disconnected");
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        String[] cmd = msg.split("\\s+");
                        System.out.println(msg);
                        if (cmd[0].equals("broadcast")) {
                            broadcast(cmd[1]);
                        } else if (cmd[0].equals("unicast")) {
                            unicast(cmd[1], cmd[2]);
                        } else if (cmd[0].equals("blockcast"))
                            blockcast(cmd[1], cmd[2]);
                        else
                            continue;

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void broadcast(String msg) throws IOException {
        for (String k : l.getMap().keySet()) {
            if (k.equals(t.getName()))
                continue;
            Socket receiverSocket = new Socket(l.getMap().get(k).getInetAddress(), l.getMap().get(k).getPort());
            PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(receiverSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            outToServer.println(msg);
        }
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    public void unicast(String cID, String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    public void blockcast(String cID, String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, when I'm creating a socket on the client side and need to refer to
>   the server, how do i go about it? If the server was on a different
>   computer, I'd provide the IP address?

You would need to provide the IP address anyhow, you *cannot* specify a server using it's class name. You always must specify the host address.

---

> `Socket clientscoket = new Socket("server.java", 2100);`

What you are doing here, is creating a `Socket` that binds to the host specified by `server.java`.

If you need to refer to the server, you should try to connect to the port on which the server listens instead of trying to access it using the class name...

---

### How do you implement it.

You can have port numbers assigned to the type of server in a factory class, that can give you `[Server]Socket`s when you need them.

*Class ConnectionFactory*

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> ports = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

static {
    // These Servers would listen to these ports.
    ports.put("com.stackoverflow.multiconnect.servers.Server1", 5001);
    ports.put("com.stackoverflow.multiconnect.servers.Server2", 5502);
    ports.put("com.stackoverflow.multiconnect.servers.Server3", 8080);
}
```

And you can have instances of both your server and client sockets returned from this class.

```
public static ServerSocket createServerSocket(Class<?> serverClass)
        throws IOException {
    return createServerSocket(serverClass.getName());
}

public static ServerSocket createServerSocket(String fqcn)
        throws IOException {
    Integer port = ports.get(fqcn);
    if (port == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No server registery found for " + fqcn);
    return new ServerSocket(port);
}

public static Socket createClientSocket(Class<?> serverClass)
        throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    return createClientSocket(serverClass.getName());
}

public static Socket createClientSocket(String fqcn)
        throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    Integer port = ports.get(fqcn);
    if (port == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No server registery found for " + fqcn);
    return new Socket("localhost", port);
}
```

Now with this, you can:

```
//Open a server Socket
ServerSocket server1 = ConnectionFactory.createServerSocket(Server1.class);    

// Create a client to connect to a server
Socket client1 = ConnectionFactory.createClientSocket(Server1.class);
```

A more elaborate and full example could be found [here](https://github.com/JExaples/quicklooks/tree/master/multiconnect).

Comment: @tinkuge don't you think that letting the client decide the port on its own a *not-so-good* idea? The Socket binds on the host **and** the port, so you can have different servers and different clients running on the same machine like a boss. And to implement it, you can create a `ServerSocketFactory` and a `ClientSocketFactory` that give you the *Sockets that you need. **Source**: Been there done that.

Comment: Well, I always thought Java would assign a port in such a way that it won't interfere with the default ports. Maybe I'm wrong. So, do you suggest specifying the client port on input as well?

Here's how my program is set up. I specify the port to be used for listening, on the server side. Then specify the same port along with server address (localhost) on the client side, so that it can open an output stream using the address-port combination.

Comment: When the output stream is established, the client sends its ID to the server using the output stream. The server accepts the connection and creates a new thread for the incoming connection where subsequent operations take place.

Here's where it gets tricky though. I use the same socket for subsequent communications from the client. I know this is not a good idea. But how do I go about creating another socket on the server side exclusively for messaging? Also, do I have to create a separate socket for communication on the client end?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that `ServerSocketFactory` creates multiple sockets as needed, depending on the number of clients connecting? Is that a good way to go about this? Because multiple clients through multiple sockets might access the same resource resulting in a race condition.

Comment: @tinkuge don't make it that complicated.... This is literally a simple approach. I will find that program in my hard disk and upload it for you....

Comment: Thank you! That would help a lot. I also updated the post with the code. The problem with current server side program is that, it works flawlessly when only one client is connected. However, when I connect a 2nd client, it enters the communication thread but for some reason, fails to read the Client ID when passed initially. I'm not sure why it isn't reading from InputStream.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but I don't see what's changed apart from library imports. Can you elaborate? And the server still doesn't behave as it needs to. The inputstream from the second client shows that there's nothing in the inputStream to read from. I am suspecting it has something to do with the first instance of the buffered reader. Any ideas?

Comment: @tinkuge I was unable to find that particular program, so I made one for you and uploaded it. I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score -1):

Try instead of server.java making use of the whole path of the directory to server.java

So home/user/class/server/server.java